# Fetch License from sandbox

Tags: salesforce1-app, licenses, android

I was able to fetch `Opportunities`, `Contacts`, `Accounts` from sandbox through SOAP api's but I did not get how to fetch `License`.

Could anybody please help me out?
Thanks.

Comment: There isn't an object named License as a standard object. Perhaps you meant `UserLicense` or `License__c`?

Comment: `lma__License__c` for the Salesforce License Management App?

Comment: @sfdcfox & user320 - It's the License we provision for an Opportunity which contains details like deployment option, exp date, java agents, .net agents etc.

Comment: @Braj You probably really mean `License__c`. Try checking your Enterprise WSDL (Setup > Develop > API > Enterprise WSDL), and let us know.

Comment: @sfdcfox - License__c is thr under 'element' in 'complexType' in my Enterprise WSDL and thr r many other complexType names like LicenseDetail__c, License_Agent__c etc. Did u mean these? and when I try to query with any of them, am getting "com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to load class: com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.License_Agent__c"... I think I need to generate partner and enterprise jar files for sandbox account... right now i have them for production account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the comments on the question, it appears that the solution is that the developer needs to use the Partner WSDL, or generate a new Enterprise WSDL that includes the missing objects for their Sandbox organization.

Comment: It was matter of generating new jar files for sandbox account... thanks @sfdcfox